# Mysterious disk space issue with rsync

Tags: linux, rsync, disk-usage

I'm not getting what's wrong with rsync about disk space.

I just bought a new external usb disk of 2TB.

I want to backup my home directory wich is in a dedicated partion on my local disk and made 69GB.

After few minutes of copy the rsync command was blocking on file in my `.cache/` dir and when I press `Ctrl+C` I get `No space left on device (28)` error.
Then I exclude my `.cache/` directory and try with some options, and even with sudo :

```
sudo rsync -avh  --progress -T /media/nixmind/ADC4-6BD7/sync_dir --delay-updates --exclude '.cache/'  /home/nixmind /media/nixmind/ADC4-6BD7
```

but it continues blocking in `.config/` as you can see in the attached picture :
[image: rsync_blocking_state]

And I still have the same disk space error when I press `Ctrl+C` (this is just an extract, there are several lines like this):

```
rsync: mkstemp "/media/nixmind/ADC4-6BD7/sync_dir/http_www-beta.tekken-card-tournament.com_0.localstorage.M1sEZ3" failed: No space left on device (28)
rsync: mkstemp "/media/nixmind/ADC4-6BD7/sync_dir/http_www-blogger-opensocial.googleusercontent.com_0.localstorage.0z54PO" failed: No space left on device (28)
rsync: mkstemp "/media/nixmind/ADC4-6BD7/sync_dir/http_www-blogger-opensocial.googleusercontent.com_0.localstorage-journal.aCTwHz" failed: No space left on device (28)
rsync: [receiver] write error: Broken pipe (32)
rsync error: received SIGINT, SIGTERM, or SIGHUP (code 20) at io.c(513) [receiver=3.1.2]
rsync: [sender] write error: Broken pipe (32)
█▓▒░nixmind@mountain-view░▒▓██▓▒░ Sun Nov 26 03:39:04am
/home/nixmind>
```

Here is my file system disk space usage :

```
█▓▒░nixmind@mountain-view░▒▓██▓▒░ Sun Nov 26 03:41:29am
/home/nixmind> df -HP
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            4.2G     0  4.2G   0% /dev
tmpfs           828M   11M  818M   2% /run
/dev/sda2        97G  7.6G   84G   9% /
tmpfs           4.2G  145M  4.0G   4% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.3M  4.1k  5.3M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           4.2G     0  4.2G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda3       148G   69G   72G  50% /home
/dev/sda5        15G   46M   14G   1% /tmp
/dev/sda4        99G  1.2G   93G   2% /var
/dev/sda1       2.0G  136k  2.0G   1% /boot/efi
/dev/loop0       88M   88M     0 100% /snap/core/3247
/dev/loop2       81M   81M     0 100% /snap/remmina/248
/dev/loop1       88M   88M     0 100% /snap/core/3017
/dev/loop3       88M   88M     0 100% /snap/core/3440
tmpfs           828M   58k  828M   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sdb        2.0T   14G  2.0T   1% /media/nixmind/ADC4-6BD7
█▓▒░nixmind@mountain-view░▒▓██▓▒░ Sun Nov 26 03:41:29am
/home/nixmind>
```

My inode usage :

```
█▓▒░nixmind@mountain-view░▒▓██▓▒░ Sun Nov 26 03:42:35am
/home/nixmind> df -Hi
Filesystem     Inodes IUsed IFree IUse% Mounted on
udev             1.1M   482  1.1M    1% /dev
tmpfs            1.1M   791  1.1M    1% /run
/dev/sda2        6.0M  323k  5.7M    6% /
tmpfs            1.1M   127  1.1M    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs            1.1M     3  1.1M    1% /run/lock
tmpfs            1.1M    15  1.1M    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda3        9.2M  439k  8.8M    5% /home
/dev/sda5        916k    46  916k    1% /tmp
/dev/sda4        6.2M   12k  6.1M    1% /var
/dev/sda1           0     0     0     - /boot/efi
/dev/loop0        14k   14k     0  100% /snap/core/3247
/dev/loop2        23k   23k     0  100% /snap/remmina/248
/dev/loop1        14k   14k     0  100% /snap/core/3017
/dev/loop3        14k   14k     0  100% /snap/core/3440
tmpfs            1.1M    39  1.1M    1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sdb            0     0     0     - /media/nixmind/ADC4-6BD7
█▓▒░nixmind@mountain-view░▒▓██▓▒░ Sun Nov 26 03:42:35am
/home/nixmind>
```

I searched everywhere, I don't understand this behavior and don't why.

Comment: what happens if you add the `-S` or `--sparse` flag to `rsync` ?

Comment: What's the output of `lsblk -fm` ?

Comment: Output of `mount | grep sdb` please, to see what type of filesystem your external disk is using.

Comment: Same behavior, same error with `--sparse` flag. I don't understand

Comment: My external disk is a fat32 file system : 

`▓▒░nixmind@mountain-view░▒▓██▓▒░ Mon Nov 27 04:45:50pm
/home/nixmind> lsblk -fm
NAME   FSTYPE   LABEL     UUID                                 MOUNTPOINT NAME     SIZE OWNER GROUP MODE
sdb    vfat     LACIE RUG ADC4-6BD7                            /media/nix sdb      1.8T root  disk  brw-rw----
█▓▒░nixmind@mountain-view░▒▓██▓▒░ Mon Nov 27 04:45:50pm
/home/nixmind> `
Should format it to nfts? I need windows compatibility, that's why I don't use linux-bases file system

Answer (score 1):

Are you uaing `fat16` or `fat32` file system on external drive? They don't support file size larger than 2gb. If so, please format the external drive with `ext3` or `ext4` and try once again.